# Is there a bug in the management of icon movement?

Tags: home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts

I have been using my Nexus one, Android Version 2.2.2, build number FRG83G, since December.
I had no problem moving icons on the screen for two months.

Lately, I think after the latest update asking to restart the android (several weeks ago), I noticed that I was not able to move the icons and widgets any more, that they would either refuse to move, disappear or be moved to some random folder on another screen (hence seemingly disappearing), and that even when there was a single icon on an otherwise empty page.

At first I thought it was a general bug which would be corrected by a following update, but it has been some time now, and googling for such bug did not yield any result, so that it seems that I am the only one suffering from such a problem. Any idea what could cause it?

Comment: What's your current build number?

Comment: build number FRG83G.  (Sorry if first line was not clear: those are the information of the current version on the phone, not those with which I received it, which are irrelevant)

Answer (score 2):

it seems this bug is fixed in 2.3.3 OTA.
to upgrade manually check http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/02/24/google-releases-android-2-3-3-update-zip-for-nexus-one-and-nexus-s/

Answer (score 1):

I would try installing a custom launcher, like ADW Launcher, Launcher Pro or Go Launcher, and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem myself; here's a couple of reports: [1](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11004) [2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10667)

If this seems to be your problem, please star the issue(s) in Google Code to vote for this being investigated.